# Xamarin ZXing initialization error and missing permission

Tags: xamarin, zxing

I have a Xamarin.Forms project which needs a QR code scanner. I decided to use the ZXing library.
The installation worked fine and I have created a DependencyService interface in the forms project so I can use the Android/iOS implementation in it. I have got the description for this from here:
http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2014/09/xamarin-scanning-qrcode-in-a-xamarin-forms-application/#.VcMrTPlNjkc

The problem I have is that there is no constructor that takes one argument. Only one which takes zero arguments.

I have the following code:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(QrCodeScanningService))]
namespace my.project.Droid.DependencyServiceImplementations
{
    public class QrCodeScanningService : IQrCodeScanningService
    {
        public async Task<string> ScanAsync()
        {
            var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(Application.Context); 
    // error: 'ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

            var scanResults = await scanner.Scan();

            return scanResults.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

The official example of ZXing uses
MobileBarcodeScanner.Initialize(Application);
But here in my application the compiler says:

```
'Android.App.Application' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

The library seems to work so far without initializing and passing the context but I don't think it is a good idea to use it this way.

Further it crashes when putting the app into the background and getting it back to the foreground with the following exception:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.Exception: Couldn't get exclusive access to the camera
[MonoDroid] at ZXing.Mobile.ZXingSurfaceView.GetExclusiveAccess () <IL 0x00033, 0x00150>
[MonoDroid] at ZXing.Mobile.ZXingSurfaceView.StartScanning (ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions,System.Action`1<ZXing.Result>) <IL 0x00046, 0x0028b>
[MonoDroid] at ZXing.Mobile.ZXingScannerFragment.scan () <IL 0x00012, 0x0007f>
[MonoDroid] at ZXing.Mobile.ZXingScannerFragment.OnResume () <IL 0x000fd, 0x00617>
[MonoDroid] at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnResume (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0000a, 0x0009f>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2ec0fbbb-3a10-48d4-b1ab-3fe72444ec91 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
```

I don't know if there is a relation between the missing initialization and this error. The camera permission is set.

Can anybody help me fixing these errors?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just know that the initialization without the context has been introduced in a recent version. It seams they didn´t update the docs and also the last versions seams to introduce new bugs. BTW I´m using 1.4.7.1 and it works

Comment: Thank you very much. You say 1.4.7.1 works - do you mean you do not have the exception when resuming the app? Is that one of the bugs they seem to have introduced?

Comment: Yes, I don´t see any exceptions when resuming the app. But there is a very random crash happening when you open the scanner view in certain devices. I say "random" because it´s not usual and I didn´t find out yet how to reproduce this error. But that version is behaving good enough for production I guess